# Why does war:exploded make no difference to the output of my Maven build?

Tags: java, maven, war

These two generate the exact same output, as verified by comparing directory listings.

```
mvn clean install

mvn clean war:exploded install
```

In each case, there is the directory of `*.class` files etc., as well as a `*.war`  generated from that.

So, if you want to work with an exploded war for your dev-environment or for certain deployment scenarios, is there any value to specifying `war:exploded`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
war:exploded
```

allows you to specify a directory in which the exploded .war is created (i.e. in a servers deployment directory).

```
mvn clean install
```

creates .class-Files etc. in the /target-dir, then packages it to a war-file.

So, the value would be to have the exploded war-file in the correct location, not in /target.